# $_POST array empty in php after submission of a form using a formData

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, forms, post

I've seen several posts about the issue but none of them solved my problem. I'm working with XAMPP and I have an html `index.html` and a php `remote.php` in the same folder.

The `formData` which I want to send to the php is created using a form (`basic_form`) in javascript. It resulted to be well constructed, since `console.log(...formData);` printed `Array [ "mode", "basic" ], Array [ "file", File ]` as expected, which are the string and the input file.

But unfortunately in the php the command `print_r($_POST);` outputs only `Array()` and also the command `var_dump($_POST);` outputs `array(0){}`. So it seems that the content of the form is not passed to the php.

Here it is the html form:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <form name="basic_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="remote.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" id="mode" name="mode" value="basic"/>
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file"/>
            <input type="submit" id="submit_basic_input" name="submit_basic_input" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here the javascript to submit the form:

```
<script>
    var basic_form = document.forms["basic_form"];
    basic_form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
        e.preventDefault(); 

        const url = 'remote.php';
        const formData = new FormData(basic_form);

        fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                if(response["status"] == 200)
                    location.replace(response["url"]);
        });
                
    });
</script>
```

Here the php to print the content of form:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
    $datapost = $_POST;
    print_r($datapost);
    print($datapost["mode"]);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you call `fetch` which makes a POST request

When you get a response, you log the response object (which doesn't hold anything all that useful, in particular the body of the response will show up as a readable stream and not a string).

That response **does** show `array(1) { ["mode"]=> string(5) "basic" } Array ( [mode] => basic ) basic` though, you can see it using the Network tab of the browser's developer tools.

After logging the response you set `location.replace(response["url"]);` which makes a GET request (to the same URL) and navigates the browser to it.

---

The GET request is a **different request** and does not have the request body from the POST request from it.

Since it is a different request, it gets a different response and now `$_POST` is an empty array.

---

If you want to navigate to the response then get rid of the JavaScript. Just make the POST request with the form and let the browser render the resulting page.

If you want to use Ajax to make the request then:

- Don't immediately navigate away from the page
- Do something useful with the response (starting by calling `response.text()` to get the data out of the response body and then perhaps using `createElement`, `appendChild` and friends to add the data to the current document)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I miss the fact that I was doing both a POST and a GET request (to be honest that `location.replace(response["url"]);` came from a template, I was not considering it harmful). I tried successfully to save to file in the php the content of `$_POST` after the POST request and it was as expected.